# 3D cube with individually rounded corners

Tags: openscad

It doesn't seem to be easy (or possible?) to get a truly rounded corners 3D cube in OpenSCAD. I tried something with `hull()` and spheres but that didn't work correctly. Then I tried to make something with hulls of circles in each plane, then intersect all 3 planes. The edges are good but the corners are not smooth. I understand that the linear extrusion of each edge is the problem because it won't follow the curve defines on another plane. I didn't get my head around the `minkowski()` function yet but it doesn't look like it would solve the problem either.

So is there any hope to get this working properly?

Here's my code so far:

```
// Lengths in X, Y, Z dimension
dx = 10;
dy = 20;
dz = 5;

// Corner radius on XY plane (from origin clockwise around positive Z axis)
rxy = [1, 1, 3, 1];
// Corner radius on YZ plane (from origin clockwise around positive X axis)
ryz = [1, 1, 1, 1];
// Corner radius on XZ plane (from origin clockwise around positive Y axis)
rxz = [1, 1, 2, 1];

intersection()
{
    // XY plane
    linear_extrude(dz)
    hull()
    {
        for (ix = [0:1], iy = [0:1])
        {
            i = [0, 1, 3, 2][ix * 2 + iy];
            r = rxy[i] == 0 ? 0.0001 : rxy[i];
            x = ix == 0 ? r : dx - r;
            y = iy == 0 ? r : dy - r;
            translate([x, y, 0])
            circle(r, $fn=40);
        }
    }

    // YZ plane
    translate([0, 0, dz])
    rotate([0, 90, 0])
    linear_extrude(dx)
    hull()
    {
        for (iy = [0:1], iz = [0:1])
        {
            i = [1, 0, 2, 3][iy * 2 + iz];
            r = ryz[i] == 0 ? 0.0001 : ryz[i];
            y = iy == 0 ? r : dy - r;
            z = iz == 0 ? r : dz - r;
            intersection()
            {
                translate([z, y, 0])
                circle(r, $fn=40);

                square([dz, dy]);
            }
        }
    }

    // XZ plane
    translate([0, dy, 0])
    rotate([90, 0, 0])
    linear_extrude(dy)
    hull()
    {
        for (ix = [0:1], iz = [0:1])
        {
            i = [0, 3, 1, 2][ix * 2 + iz];
            r = rxz[i] == 0 ? 0.0001 : rxz[i];
            x = ix == 0 ? r : dx - r;
            z = iz == 0 ? r : dz - r;
            intersection()
            {
                translate([x, z, 0])
                circle(r, $fn=40);

                square([dx, dz]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The corners look like this:

[image]

One application of this would be a shape like this thing: https://www.printables.com/model/62314-cable-clamp#preview
It has slightly rounded corners everywhere and a massively rounded corner at exactly one edge.

Comment: I want to try building this from a hull of 8 corner shapes whose geometry I've asked for in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74116928/143684).

Answer (score 3):

There is an OpenSCAD [module](https://danielupshaw.com/openscad-rounded-corners/) that does this. That page also lists a link to a [simple version](https://gist.github.com/groovenectar/292db1688b79efd6ce11) that uses Minkowski. Here is the code from the simple version.

```
// More information: https://danielupshaw.com/openscad-rounded-corners/

module roundedcube_simple(size = [1, 1, 1], center = false, radius = 0.5) {
    // If single value, convert to [x, y, z] vector
    size = (size[0] == undef) ? [size, size, size] : size;

    translate = (center == false) ?
        [radius, radius, radius] :
        [
            radius - (size[0] / 2),
            radius - (size[1] / 2),
            radius - (size[2] / 2)
    ];

    translate(v = translate)
    minkowski() {
        cube(size = [
            size[0] - (radius * 2),
            size[1] - (radius * 2),
            size[2] - (radius * 2)
        ]);
        sphere(r = radius);
    }
}
```

`radius * 2` is subtracted from the cube dimensions since Minkowski adds the radius to all sides.

Comment: Where can I set an individual radius for each edge here?

Answer (score 2):

I found a partial solution to your problem : you can only determine 6 radii (all the radii of the edges of the top face are the same and the same thing applies to the bottom face) but I think it's enough for the example you shown.

code:

```
module rounded_cube(size = [4, 2, 1], face_radii = [1/8, 1/16], edges_radii = [1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, ], $fn = 16){
    
    module block(size = [1, 2], radii = [1/2, 1/4], $fn = 16){
        intersection(){
            union(){
                square([size.x - radii[0], radii[0]]);
                translate([0, size.y - radii[1]])
                square([size.x - radii[1], radii[1]]);
                
                translate([0, radii[0]])
                square([size.x, size.y - radii[0] - radii[1]]);
            
                translate([size.x - radii[0], radii[0]])
                circle(radii[0]);
                translate([size.x - radii[1], size.y - radii[1]])
                circle(radii[1]);
            }
            square([size.x, size.y]);
        }
    }

    //block();
    
    assert(max(face_radii) <= min(edges_radii), "all face radii must be smaller than all edges radii");
    
    assert(face_radii[0] + face_radii[1] <= size.z, "the sum of the face radii must be smaller than the height of the rounded cube");
    
    assert(
        edges_radii[0] + edges_radii[1] <= size.x &&
        edges_radii[1] + edges_radii[2] <= size.y &&
        edges_radii[2] + edges_radii[3] <= size.x &&
        edges_radii[3] + edges_radii[0] <= size.y, 
        "the sum of two consecutive edges radii must be smaller than the side they lie on");

    for(e = [0 : 3]){
        translate([size.x * [0, 1, 1, 0][e], size.y * [0, 0, 1, 1][e]])
        rotate([0, 0, 180 + e*90]){
            translate([-edges_radii[e], -edges_radii[e]])
            rotate_extrude(angle = 90, $fn = $fn * 4)
            block([edges_radii[e], size.z], [face_radii[0], face_radii[1]], $fn = $fn * 4);
            
            rotate([-90, 0, 90])
            translate([-size[(e + 1) % 2] / 2, -size.z, edges_radii[e]])
            linear_extrude(size[e % 2] - edges_radii[e] - edges_radii[(e + 1) % 4])
            block([size[(e + 1) % 2] / 2, size.z], [face_radii[1], face_radii[0]], $fn = $fn * 4);
        }
    }
}

rounded_cube(size = [4, 2, 1], face_radii = [1/8, 1/16], edges_radii = [1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8], $fn = 16);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also worth to look at is the immensive NopSCADLib, especially: https://github.com/nophead/NopSCADlib?tab=readme-ov-file#rounded_rectangle

Example:

```
rounded_cube_xy(size, r = 0, xy_center = false, z_center = false)
```

Like cube() but corners rounded in XY plane and separate centre options for xy and z.