# How to construct a shape of half circles with a different radius in each axis?

Tags: openscad

For my other question [how to build a cuboid with individually rounded edges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72537595/143684) (different edge radius on each edge) I want to try out using a spherical-like shape to put in all 8 corners and apply a hull over them.

For this I need a corner base geometry that has the following properties:

1. Around an axis (X, Y, Z), on the plane orthogonal to it, the 2D outline geometry consists of two half circles with a radius *r* ≥ 0 that are by the distance *d* ≥ 0 apart.
2. #1 applies to each axis independently. That is, when viewing from any axis direction (not from somewhere tilted), the outline will look as described above, but with potentially different *r* and *d*.
3. This will result in either

   - a regular sphere (if all *r* are equal and all *d* are 0) or
   - a filled torus (if one *r* is greater than the other two equal *r*) or
   - a combination thereof, with different flat areas ≥ 0 around each axis.

Some dependencies apply so that the radius/distance of certain axes must be the same as for another axis to maintain the above properties. For example, in the illustration below for the Z axis (viewing the XY projection), the same distance must be used in the XZ plane so that the shape looks like a full circle from the Y axis. (I hope I haven't mixed things up now.)

Here's an illustration of these parameters:

[image: illustration]

The red center mark shows the axis being considered for this projection. The black line shows the projected outline around that axis, with the two half circles and a flat connection between their ends, as long as the distance.

This should be applied for all three axes. I'm looking for a way with OpenSCAD to construct the resulting 3D shape. I cannot fully imagine how it will look but I believe that it should be possible to build a geometry that satisfies the above requirements.

What code do I need to achieve this?

I've tried with scaling a sphere in all 3 axes but that obviously won't meet the two-half-circles outline with flat caps. It also results in undesired effects on the hull of the target application.

I've tried building this base corner shape with another hull but that won't result in a circle but rather a rounded square from one direction. I'm running out of ideas how to build this.

Answer (score 1):

Is that not just a cube, with some part removed? And so is your original question (it is only when viewing it that this one made sense).

I am really not sure to understand what you have in mind, because some constraints seems contradictory to me.

First of all, you specified no orientation. I understand (also from the other question) that there are 3 privileges axis (otherwise, just a plane, defined by its normal, still have an infinity of rotation around its axis). But even forcing the 3 axis, and taking into account the symmetry of what you want, there are still two possibilities: should your object look like your drawing in the XY projection, Z being normal. Or should it look like this in the YX projection, Z being normal?

So, there is also an order implied: for example XY, YZ, ZX. Or XY, YZ, XZ. You can't have both (unless d=0).

Another remark is that the `distance` are linked to the `radius`. `distance+2×radius` from one project, is the `2×radius` of another (depending on the above mentioned "order", but there is no order not causing at least one such collision).

With all this in mind, my proposal (I've no doubt that you'll probably reject it. But if the rejection comment helps to understand what you have in mind...)

```
module both(a){
    children();
    mirror(a) children();
}

module shape(d1, d2, d3){
    intersection(){
        hull() both([1,0,0]) translate([-d1/2+d3/2,-d2/2,0]) rotate([-90,0,0]) cylinder(r=d3/2, h=d2);
        hull() both([1,0,0]) translate([-d1/2+d2/2, 0, -d3/2]) cylinder(r=d2/2, h=d3);
        hull() both([0,1,0]) translate([-d1/2, -d2/2+d3/2,0]) rotate([0,90,0]) cylinder(r=d3/2, h=d1);
    }
}
```

It is meant to be used with d1 ≥ d2 ≥ d3. And to be then rotated as fit.

It has the correct shape from all 6 faces

[image]

Note that when all 3 dimensions are the same, it doesn't look like a sphere, but like the intersection of 3 cylinders. That is the maximum enveloppe of all figures whose projections are the one you've asked for. But so does the images of the example shown in your other question.

What would converge to a sphere, would be a hull of 8 spheres. That is the classical way to have rounded cuboids.  But you seemed to eject this solution (even tho, you could have different radius to all spheres). Plus, the hull of 8 spheres do not have the projection you've asked for.